# Write to Z OS Flat file is failing in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, io, spring-batch, zos

While writing to a Z O/s flat file in spring batch the job is failing with below error:

Error:

> 'HLQ1.TEST.POC.OUT': Filename is not a valid MVS dataset or DD name;errno=99 errno2=0x0

Specification of DD in JCL (Mainframe)

```
//MYOUT    DD DSN=HLQ1.TEST.POC.OUT,DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
```

Spring Batch:

```
ZFileResource fileLocator=new ZFileResource("MYOUT");
```

Comment: **BATCH-FILE** Is a kind of Windows script!!! **Do not** confuse it with spring-batch please!

Comment: @SteveFest ,This is to execute Spring Java batch from Mainframe using JCL (Job Control Language). This is similar to Windows Batch-file. This process worked for Reading Mainframe Flat file. Now, I am trying for the WRITE operation.

Comment: Do you know what Windows batch file is? Is your question even related to Windows batch?

Comment: This is not related to Windows Batch.

Comment: Correct. So that's why I removed the tag.

Comment: Is HLQ1 a valid high level qualifier on your z/OS? Normally you have to request RACF security settings by your system administrator. You cannot create files as you like on z/OS.